# Google Drive uploading issue with Google drive SDK

Tags: symfony, google-api, google-drive-api

We are facing an issue in file uploading with Google drive SDK.
Our Symfony application is uploading a file to Google drive. The uploading was successful, but drive not listing the files. The file is existing in the drive, it confirmed by accessing via a link.

Is it related to any Drive permission issue or API related issue? Can anyone help us with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your question and include enough of your code to show the issue.   We cant help you fix issues without knowing more information.

Comment: Are you sure that the account you uploaded to is the same account you are checking?

Answer (score 0):

did you check the parent directory parameter?, if it is null the file is stored into your account but outside your root folder, it happened to me a couple of times.